# Microsoft Graph API People API Failed to search in User Created Folders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$Search="contact1"

Result is empty if contact1 is under a user created folder - Folder1.

How can we search for COntacts from all Folders using a Single API call?

Comment: Based on your information, i'm unclear about your question. 
Do you want to retrieve all the contact information under the folder with API: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactfolders/{Id}/contacts`,  ?
Or  you want to retrieve all the people by the API `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people`?  
Could you provide more detail info for you question?

Comment: There are 2 UseCases, I have .

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response. 

There are 2 UseCases that I have.

1. I want to search for Email-addresses for Sending Email. I can use People API. But People API does not return EmailAddresses from My Contacts if it is nested under a Contact Folder. 

2. Use Case 2 - Contacts Search by DisplayName for all my Contacts.  If I have to search by including Contact Folder in API, - The number of API Calls increases as the number of Folders Increase - The Search Results Wait time increases.  Just wanted to check if there is any API to Search for Contacts that returns results from all Folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the questions and the comments you posted, I suppose you want to get the email-address of the people under a Contact Folder and get all contacts under the contacts folder.

For your case 1, according to the description of the content [Use the People API in Microsoft Graph to get information about the people most relevant to you,](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/people_example) we can get the people most relevant to the signed-in user (`/me`), or to a specific user in the signed-in user’s organization, instead of the people under a Contact Folder.

For your case 2, we use the API for getting the contacts, It will only return contacts under the default folder. Single contact file directories can only be obtained through [this API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contactfolder_get). We can refer to [the simple code in this content to get contacts in the contact folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760194/get-contacts-from-all-outlook-contact-folders-microsoft-graph/51768863#51768863)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try that.